# Splitting text from number in python using pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, nlp

I have a string

```
x='125mg'
```

First, i want to detect that number and text are together and if they are together so i want to separate it into `125` and `mg`.

Comment: Make sure that you explain the question in details and also make sure to include the code you have written.

Comment: Search About how to use Regular Regular expression in python

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re

a = '125mg switch'
' '.join(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', a))
```

Output:

```
  '125 mg switch'
```

Comment: Please explain your code in your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the very simple task in python using the regular expresiion package in python .Here i am providing u the code for splitting the number from the string:

python code:

```
import re
a='125msg'
result=re.findall('\d+',a)
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Comment: a='125mg swich' so at the output i want is 125 mg swich

Comment: you can use `re.sub(r"(\d+)", r"\1 ", a)` to convert `"125mg switch"` to `"125 mg switch"`

Comment: @AliZarezade this will generate two spaces when there is actually a space between 125 and mg.

Comment: @BICube That is right. Actually it depends on the use case. Maybe if multiple space is not desired, then using `b=re.sub(r"(\d+)", r"\1 ", a)` and then `c=re.sub(r"\s+", r" ", b)` would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it using Regular Expression in Python. I don't know whether pandas can do that. 
read more about it from [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

```html
import re

test_str  = "125mg"
res = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', test_str)
print(str(res))
```